# Why is numpy.ravel returning a copy?

Tags: python, numpy

In the following example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = a[:,np.newaxis]
>>> c = b.ravel()
>>> np.may_share_memory(a,c)
False
```

Why is `numpy.ravel` returning a copy of my array? Shouldn't it just be returning `a`?

Edit:

I just discovered that `np.squeeze` *doesn't* return a copy.

```
>>> b = a[:,np.newaxis]
>>> c = b.squeeze()
>>> np.may_share_memory(a,c)
True
```

Why is there a difference between `squeeze` and `ravel` in this case?

Edit:

As pointed out by mgilson, `newaxis` marks the array as discontiguous, which is why `ravel` is returning a copy.

So, the new question is why is `newaxis` marking the array as discontiguous.

The story gets even weirder though:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = np.expand_dims(a,axis=1)
>>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> c = b.ravel()
>>> np.may_share_memory(a,c)
True
```

According to the documentation for `expand_dims`, it should be equivalent to `newaxis`.

Comment: According to the documentation a copy is made when necessary - perhaps the reshaping means numpy decides it's necessary...

Comment: It is possible (likely) that numpy may have code internally to deal with strange striding (to optimize either broadcast or access speed) and `ravel` will undo all of those to flatten them, where as `squeeze` probably just knocks off dimensions with dimension=1.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the best answer to your question, but it looks like inserting a newaxis causes numpy to view the array as non-contiguous -- probably for broadcasting purposes:

```
>>> a=np.arange(10)
>>> b=a[:,None]
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

However, a reshape will not cause that:

```
>>> c=a.reshape(10,1) 
>>> c.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

And those arrays do share the same memory:

```
>>> np.may_share_memory(c.ravel(),a)
True
```

**EDIT**

`np.expand_dims` is actually implemented using `reshape` which is why it works (This is a slight error in documentation I suppose).  Here's the source (without the docstring):

```
def expand_dims(a,axis):
    a = asarray(a)
    shape = a.shape
    if axis < 0:
        axis = axis + len(shape) + 1
    return a.reshape(shape[:axis] + (1,) + shape[axis:])
```

Comment: Yeah, I was about to post the same thing. Weird, right? I'm really curious what's going on under the hood here.

Comment: @senderle -- I'm guessing it is for broadcasting for one reason or another.  But I'm curious as well.

Comment: Very interesting! Check out my updates to the question. I hope we can get a numpy developer over here to explain this.

Comment: @user545424 -- Under the hood, `np.expand_dims` uses `reshape`.  (it constructs a tuple of dimensions inserting a `(1,)` in the middle.  So, the documentation is slightly wrong ;^) -- Although it would be easy enough to create a tuple with newaxis and slices ... to make the behavior correct.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it may have to do with the strides:

```
>>> c = np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)
>>> c.strides
(8, 8)

>>> b = a[:, None]
>>> b.strides
(8, 0)
>>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> b.strides = (8, 8)
>>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

I'm not sure what difference the stride on dimension 1 could make here, but it looks like that's what's making numpy treat the array as not contiguous.